# google map is displaying to small in top left corner

Tags: google-maps

In a webapp I´m loading a page (googlemap.asp with the map) with ajax.

I´m loading the "googlemap.asp" in a div with jquery.load and it is only displaying a small map in the top left corner, so its not getting the size 320 x 600 as I have set in the div. 
It is not rendering the map correctly when I load it this way.

But if I just load the "googlemap.asp" directly in the browser(without ajax) then it displays right, so I guess I have to refreash it somehow when I load it with ajax?

This is what I have:

```
 <div id="map_canvas" style="height:600px; width:320px;" ></div>

window.onload=googleMaploadScript();


function googleMaploadScript() {
    var script =document.createElement("script");
    script.type="text/javascript";
    script.src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);  
    }

var address1 = document.getElementById('address').value;


var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(57.109577,12.286513),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);  
  codeAddress(address1);

}

function codeAddress(address) {
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location,
      });    
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });

}
```

I guess I load it in the wrong order somehow, and thats why it is not rendering right, or could it be that the div is not visible at start?

Any input appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing Height and Width from Script.

Comment: I tryed to set the height and width in the "mapOptions" but it didn´t work.

Comment: ok, I set the height and width in the mapOptins and it works in the iPhone but not on the desktop safari. But now it is not centered? The center is in the top left corner?

Answer (score 0):

For centering add this script to your map script it will center it . But I am also having trouble to bring it from top left to center. In my case when I change the orientation or size the map loads and centered

//script for centering

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
                                var center = map.getCenter();
                                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                                map.setCenter(center); 
                            });
```

Let me know if it works . Here is the [**LINK**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669869/how-to-make-the-google-map-work-like-google-map-application-in-android-phones) for more information