# How to make the google map work like google map application in android phones

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile

As you can see in the picture I have the zoom in zoom out button at the bottom left corner of the screen . I want to make it move little bit up or maybe add some new css to it so that its easier to use . Can some one help me out with this how to change this one ?

[image]

Thanks & Regards

**.JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">          
/*
 * Google Maps documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html
 * Geolocation documentation: http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html
*/
$( document ).on( "pageshow", "#map-page", function() {
    <?php $coordenadas=explode(',',$fila['Googlemap']);?>

   var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng('<?php echo $coordenadas[0];?>','<?php echo $coordenadas[1];?>');
    drawMap(defaultLatLng); // Default to Hollywood, CA when no geolocation support
     //var latlng = marker.getPosition();
    function drawMap(latlng) {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
        // Add an overlay to the map of current lat/lng
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Greetings!"
        });
        $( window ).resize(function() {
       google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                      });

        map.setCenter(defaultLatLng);
    }

}); 
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div  data-shadow="false" data-theme="c"  id="map-page"  data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" style="background:#006699 !important;color:#fff;">
<a data-rel="back" href="#pageone"  class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-new-btn" data-icon="location" data-iconpos="notext"  data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="d" title="Close">Go to Page One</a>
<h1><?php echo $translate->text('Ubicación Aproximada')?> </h1>
<a data-rel="back"  href="#pageone"  class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-new-btn" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext"  data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="d" title="Close">Back</a> 
</div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="map-canvas">
        <!-- map loads here... -->
    <!---</div> ---->
</div>
</div>


</div>
```

**Edit1**

Added the following script to

```
$(window).bind( 'orientationchange', function(e){
    var ori = window.orientation ;
        w = (ori==90 || ori==-90) ? screen.height : screen.width;
        h = (ori==90 || ori==-90) ? screen.width : screen.height;
         $('#map-canvas').width(w);
         $('#map-canvas').height($(window).height()- $('#head1').height());


    });
```

results into [image]

**Answer**

Here is the answer to my question it works just like the google map application in mobile device

```
<script type="text/javascript">          
/*
 * Google Maps documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html
 * Geolocation documentation: http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html
*/


$( document ).on( "pageshow", "#map-page", function() {
    <?php $coordenadas=explode(',',$fila['Googlemap']);?>

   var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng('<?php echo $coordenadas[0];?>','<?php echo $coordenadas[1];?>'); 

   $('#map-canvas').height( $(window).height() - $('#head1').height());
    drawMap(defaultLatLng); // Default to Hollywood, CA when no geolocation support
     //var latlng = marker.getPosition();
    function drawMap(latlng) {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: latlng,
            streetViewControl:true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

        // Add an overlay to the map of current lat/lng
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Greetings!"
        });
        // this is our gem
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
            var center = map.getCenter();
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            map.setCenter(center); 
        }); 
}       
}); 
$(window).bind( 'orientationchange', function(e){
          var ori = window.orientation ;
            w = (ori==90 || ori==-90) ? window.height : window.width;
            $('#map-canvas').width(w);
            $('#map-canvas').height( $(window).height() - $('#head1').height());    

    }); 
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Post the code you have tried or make a fiddle of it

Comment: @Richa updated please check my updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I could fix the problem totally

Here is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">          
/*
 * Google Maps documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html
 * Geolocation documentation: http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html
*/


$( document ).on( "pageshow", "#map-page", function() {
    <?php $coordenadas=explode(',',$fila['Googlemap']);?>

   var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng('<?php echo $coordenadas[0];?>','<?php echo $coordenadas[1];?>'); 

   $('#map-canvas').height( $(window).height() - $('#head1').height());
    drawMap(defaultLatLng); // Default to Hollywood, CA when no geolocation support
     //var latlng = marker.getPosition();
    function drawMap(latlng) {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: latlng,
            streetViewControl:true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

        // Add an overlay to the map of current lat/lng
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Greetings!"
        });
        // this is our gem
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
            var center = map.getCenter();
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            map.setCenter(center); 
        }); 
}       
}); 
$(window).bind( 'orientationchange', function(e){
          var ori = window.orientation ;
            w = (ori==90 || ori==-90) ? window.height : window.width;
            $('#map-canvas').width(w);
            $('#map-canvas').height( $(window).height() - $('#head1').height());    

    }); 
</script>
```

Now it centers Just like Google Map application in Android devices

Answer (score 3):

It was happening because My page had a header and the size of div with id #map-canvas was given equal to window size . If not given then its default I guess .

So I extracted the size of the header and minus it with the size of the window and set it to map-canvas.

Like this

```
 var  v = $( window ).height();
        h= $('#head1').height();
        v = v - h;
   $('#map-canvas').height(v);
```

or

```
$('#map-canvas').height( $(window).height() - $('#head1').height());
```

So my complete code looks something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">          
/*
 * Google Maps documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html
 * Geolocation documentation: http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html
*/
$( document ).on( "pageshow", "#map-page", function() {
    <?php $coordenadas=explode(',',$fila['Googlemap']);?>

   var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng('<?php echo $coordenadas[0];?>','<?php echo $coordenadas[1];?>'); 
   var  v = $( window ).height();
        h= $('#head1').height();
        v = v - h;
   $('#map-canvas').height(v);
    drawMap(defaultLatLng); // Default to Hollywood, CA when no geolocation support
     //var latlng = marker.getPosition();
    function drawMap(latlng) {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

        // Add an overlay to the map of current lat/lng
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Greetings!"
        });
        $( window ).resize(function() {
       google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                      });

        map.setCenter(defaultLatLng);
    }

}); 
</script>
```

Comment: But in this answer there is a problem  . That when mobile changes the orientation the dimension of the div #map-canvas should change according which is not happening

Comment: Let me give you an advice. If you are satisfied with this (your) answer accept it (you can do it for your own questions) so others can see it as working solution. Regarding your last problem you should open another question dedicated only to it. PS. Congrats on solved problem

Comment: Thanks for the advice :) , Actually Stack was not letting me accept my own answer so i updated in my question :D